AutoCAD 2024 SPLINE command in SCR file
I want to load a script file in AutoCAD 2024, and in the file I'm telling it to write PLINE coords and SPLINE coords. My problem is that I need to change the SPLINE method to CV (it defaults to fit). For the life of me I can't figure it out (and so it's drawing my spline incorrectly). I know in the command line, I could change the Method to CV, but I need to write the equivalent in code, and it's not letting me put a method in there. Is there a secret to this or is it just not possible?
I've tried SETVAR SPLMETHOD 1 at the top of the script, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.
This is what my code looks like:
PLINE 1128424.2669270784,106197.22916667163 1128431.6315104216,106204.31380209327 ARC S 1128448.7677760532,106221.07773843795 1128456.810546875,106243.66080729663 
SPLINE 1128456.810546875,106243.66080729663 1128476.1194806003,106338.64530387289 1128513.0118417114,106314.55676220624 1128526.466796875,106405.48567709327   
PLINE 1128526.466796875,106405.48567709327 1128528.63671875,106463.42838542163 1128522.77734375,106470.58984375

I've tried:
SPLINE
M
CV
1128456.810546875,106243.66080729663 ...

But that doesn't seem to work either...
When it reaches the "M" it's expecting that to be the first point.

If the used AutoCAD version supports AutoLISP, you can force the command to use the last version with the initcommandversion function.
(initcommandversion)
_SPLINE
_M
_CV
1128456.810546875,106243.66080729663
1128476.1194806003,106338.64530387289
1128513.0118417114,106314.55676220624
1128526.466796875,106405.48567709327 

